# Propositional Calculus, Can someone answer the following?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Can somebody please solve the following equations:
\begin{align}
1.  \quad  (A \rightarrow  B)\land (A\rightarrow \neg B)=\lnot A   \quad  \quad \\ 
\end{align}
What I have got for it so far is

$$(¬A\lor B)\land (¬A\lor ¬B)\\
(¬A\lor B)∧¬A \lor (¬A\lor B)∧¬B\\
(¬A\lor ¬A)\lor (B∧¬A) \lor (¬A∧¬B) \lor(B∧¬B)$$

After this I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: easy. for example: (A=>B)∧(A=>¬B)=A=>(B∧¬B)=¬A

Comment: use true table.

Comment: It tells me to answering using Boolean Algebra!

Comment: If you have to use BA, the "best thing" is to remove $\implies$ : $A \implies B = \lnot A \lor B$. In this way, you can "solve" 1. and 3. in one shot ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \begin{align} (A \rightarrow B)\wedge (A\rightarrow \lnot B)
& \equiv (\lnot A\lor B)\land (\lnot A \lor \lnot B)\tag{Implication}\\
&\equiv \lnot A \lor (B \land \lnot B)\tag{Distribution}\\
& \equiv\lnot A \lor 0\\
&\equiv \lnot A
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align} A\rightarrow (B\rightarrow C) &\equiv \lnot A \lor (\lnot B \lor C) \tag{Implication $\times 2$}\\
&\equiv (\lnot A \lor \lnot B)\lor C \tag{Associativity of $\lor$}\\
&\equiv \lnot(A\land B) \lor C\tag{DeMorgan's}\\
&\equiv (A\land B)\rightarrow C\tag{Implication}
\end{align}$$

Now go back and try working out the third exercise, using any or all of the above identities. If you'd like to check out what you get for $(3)$, feel free to comment below this post.

Comment: Thank you Jordan Glen.
I did not know the (DIstribution) bit

Comment: You're welcome, Patrick!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it: Suppose $A$ is true. Then we can obtain the contradiction $B\land\neg B$ from the two implications. So, $A$ must be false, i.e. we have $\neg A$.